# Divisibility of Determinant of matrix

Tags: matrices, prime-numbers, divisibility, determinant

Let $p$ be an odd prime number and $T_p$ be the following set of $2\times 2$ matrices

$$
T_p= \biggl\{A = \begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & a\end{bmatrix} 
\,\Big\vert\: a,b,c \in \{ 0, 1, 2, ... p-1\}\biggr \}
$$

The number of $A$ in $T_p$ such that $\det(A)$ is not divisible by $p$ is?

I tried solving this by subtracting the determinants divisible by $p$ from total number of matrices. The total number of matrices in $T_p$ is $p^3$. If $a=0$ then either $b$ or $c$ should also be zero.
 Hence there are $2p-1$ cases for $a= 0$ and $\det(A)$ is divisible.

Dont know what to do for non zero $a$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you explain why you say "|A| = zero should have a=0 and either b or c should also be zero"? That doesn't seem correct to me after a quick look. (You can edit your question to add this info by clicking on "edit" beneath the question).

Comment: Also: I've fixed up your MathJax to look prettier; you might want to take a look at what I've done so that you can do the same in the future.

Comment: @JohnHughes Yes that was a mistake. I meant so say a=0

Comment: That's still not quite right...the determinant is $a^2 - bc$. If $a = 0$ and $b = c = 1$, that's not divisible by $p$. You need to think a little harder about all solutions to $a^2 = bc \bmod p$.

Comment: @JohnHughes But if I am trying to find only divisible cases and subtracting from total no. then I don't have to look at cases where a is zero and b and c are both greater than zero. If p cannot divide both b and c, and it is prime then it does not divide bc either.

Comment: The question is not whether $p$ divides $bc$; the question is whether $p$ divides $a^2 - bc$, which is the determinant of $A$. **One** way for that to happen is for $p$ to divide *both* $a^2$ and $bc$, but there are other possibilities as well. For $p = 5$, for instance, we have $a = 2, b = 1, c = 4$, and $a = 3, b = 1, c = 1$. There are others as well...why not try to work them all out in the $p = 5$ case?